# PHP CURL error 18 on Chunked Requests (Hidden Timeout Variable)

Tags: php, scala, curl, guzzle, chunked

I've been going crazy because of a timeout that is occurring on chunked requests with PHP version 5.5 and curl version 7.51.0. PHP is requesting a set of data from a Scala Play Framework service, which is returning a chunked response.

What's happening: As soon as the PHP request waits 60 seconds for the next chunk, it terminates with a CURL error 18. This same endpoint works with requests of smaller sizes, so I know that it's not a general connection issue.

Testing the endpoint from the PHP box via command line using a request of this format works without issue:

```
curl -i -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '<Request Params>' <URL>
```

My PHP Request (using guzzle shown here, but I've also tried raw curl exec) looks like this:

```
$client->request('POST', $route, [
            // I thought this would work first  
            'timeout' => 120,
            // Maybe some of these other timeouts will help...
            'connect_timeout' => 120,
            'read_timeout' => 120,
            'json' => $body,
            'headers' => [
                // I found some random SOs that suggest setting headers..
                'Connection' => 'close',
                'Expect' => '',
                'Transfer-Encoding' => 'chunked'
                ],
            'stream' => true,
                'curl' => [
                        // Beginning the descent into insanity 
                        CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 120,
                        // I don't have a low speed limit set but maybe?
                        CURLOPT_LOW_SPEED_TIME => 120,
                        // Perhaps there's a guzzle bug that doesn't set timeout.. NOPE  
                        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 120,
                        // Hey, this one works! We'll see in the curlinfo below
                        CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT => true,
                        CURLOPT_VERBOSE => true,
                        CURLOPT_STDERR => '<logloc>',
                        // alright this isn't even a socket connection but sure 
                        CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE => true,
                        // SET ALL OF THE TIMEOUTS!!
                        CURLOPT_TCP_KEEPALIVE => 120,
                        CURLOPT_TCP_KEEPIDLE => 120,
                        CURLOPT_TCP_KEEPINTVL => 120
                ]
        ]);
```

None of the above worked. Some suggestions recommend that I set HTTP version to 1.0. That is an unnacceptable solution, as the data returned from this endpoint needs to be streamed directly in the response (hence stream => true). The same problem occurs with raw curl (without Guzzle).

In addition to the above request settings, I've set the following PHP settings:

```
set_time_limit(0); // also have set this to large numbers
ini_set("default_socket_timeout", 270); // Have also set this in the PHP.ini
```

The curl stats of the failed response are

```
{
    "url": "<URL>",
    "content_type": "text/plain; charset=utf-8",
    "http_code": 200,
    "header_size": 144,
    "request_size": 207,
    "filetime": -1,
    "ssl_verify_result": 0,
    "redirect_count": 0,
    "total_time": 60.20854, // WHY CRUEL WORLD??
    "namelookup_time": 0.124769,
    "connect_time": 0.125011,
    "pretransfer_time": 0.132244,
    "size_upload": 116,
    "size_download": 51,
    "speed_download": 0,
    "speed_upload": 1,
    "download_content_length": -1,
    "upload_content_length": -1,
    "starttransfer_time": 0.132248,
    "redirect_time": 0,
    "redirect_url": "",
    "primary_ip": "<>",
    "certinfo": [],
    "primary_port": 443,
    "local_ip": "<>",
    "local_port": 39562,
    "request_header": "POST <URL> HTTP/1.1 Host: <HOST> User-Agent: GuzzleHttp/6.2.1 curl/7.51.0 PHP/5.5.38 Content-Type: application/json Connection: close Transfer-Encoding: chunked "
}
```

Then it throws:

```
cURL error 18: transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html
```

To sum up..

I've set a number of timeout variables, but none that I've set have been able to rid me of this insanity. Can anyone show me the light?

Comment: Can you just type the curl command in the terminal and check it ?

Comment: As mentioned, "Testing the endpoint from the PHP box via command line using a request of this format works without issue:

curl -i -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '<Request Params>' <URL>"

Comment: Facing same issue. Anyone with the solution please?

Comment: @SheaHawkins ever found a solution to your problem? I've got a big suspicion I might be having the same problem.